# Problem with URL in IIS7.5 + Sharepoint Services in TFS2010

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

my question is kinda simple but i just don't know how to get it.

I have this dedicated server at home, used almost just for Team Foundation Server, I did the single server configuration wizard so I have Sharepoint Services running along with SQL Server and IIS 7.5, the problem is that every single link and URL on the sharepoint sites are generated from the local Computer name, which is TFS.

I have a domain (example.com) and a subdomain pointing to my home Static Ip address, the router properly configurated and so on, and if you hit tfs.example.com you get the Sharepoint home page, but any link are generated as i said, example, http://tfs/Lists/Announcements/AllItems.aspx.

I want to know if there's any way to fix this. What I've done before is to go to all the clients PC and set a windows host rule, so any request to say, TFS, it gets to my IP, but I want to avoid this, and set something on the server to change all that routes. Anything like URL rewrite or something. There's no domain, and all the clients connects trough Internet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the Alternate Access Mappings (AAM) correctly.

Specifically - tfs.example.com needs to be the **default** AAM.

- For SharePoint 2007

  *SharePoint Central Administration > Operations > Alternate Access Mappings > Edit Public URL's*
- For SharePoint 2010

  *SharePoint Central Administration > System Settings > Configure alternate access mappings -> Edit Public URL's*

Comment: Thanks!!! I set it up as i wrote to http://blog.jpwebdevelop.com/2010/07/configurar-tfs-para-subdominios-de.html Someway like you said. Thanks!